# Access as front-end for SQL Server Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have recently converted my Access (2010) database to SQL server (2008) and am attempting to use Access as the front-end. The issues I am having are with sorting and filtering columns within Access. Sorting essentially doesn't work for most columns - does not end up with alphabetically/numerically ordered rows. Also filtering columns will not work consistently either. It will sometimes perform the first filter correctly, but when I change the criteria it will not work and typically shows 0 rows.

I have looked around, but can't seem to find anyone else running into this issue. Are these known bugs with this configuration?

Also, are there any other alternatives similar to Access as a front-end for SQL server? My users require similar functionality that Access provides - filter, sorting, editing data, and they do not want to write any SQL to do this. I would like to not have to create a custom front-end, but I am starting to think this may be my only option.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you retrieving your data? Are you using ADO or ODBC linked tables? What mechanisms or code are you using to sort and filter? I use Access 2007/2010 with SQL Server 2008 Express and I don't have any of these issues. But I am using ODBC Linked Tables and I presume you are using ADO or Pass Through Queries to retrieve data from SQL Server.

Comment: How are you linking the tables to the Access front-end?  Are you doing internal links or SQL connection string with queries?

Comment: If your users are used to having this amount of freedom with the data, and as you have now migrated to SQL Server, I suggest you install the SQL server software on their machines and teach them how to use it : )

Comment: Matt - That is ideally what I would like to do, but I don't think it will happen. They don't want to delve into the world of SQL.

Comment: HK1 - The latest test I did was using ADP, but as others have pointed out below, that is being phased out, so I will not be using that. I have also used the up-sizing wizard, but ran into the same issue there. I believe this is the same as using ODBC linked tables, but will look into this.

Also, the sorting and filtering that is not working is the one native to Access. I'll see if the ODBC linked tables fixes this.

Comment: Ok, so I am now using the ODBC linked table headers and it seems to be an improvement :), but have a new issue. When there is a column that refers to a foreign key ID and it is displaying another column, the filtering/sorting is still based on the ID, rather than text. I have attempted to play around with the design view, but can't figure out how to fix this. An example of this scenario would be referencing a Security ID, but displaying the Bloomberg Symbol.

Comment: A word of warning, if for any of your indexes you use the SQL type of **Big Int**, it will be out of the range supported by access and they may show as **#Deleted** unless you open them in a snapshot view, however this will then not allow you to edit the data.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I have not used Access much as a front-end to SQL Server.

Came across [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-access-to-build-a-front-end-for-sql-server/5065669) article on using a new feature of Access, "Access Data Project", that might be something to look at. It seems to offer a little bit more functionality than the traditional method of linked tables in Access. Allows for a little bit more use of SQL Server T-SQL features than having to depend on Access's native language.

Comment: I've seen this article previously and have created an ADP, but it did not solve the filtering/sorting issues I am having.

Comment: ADP's (Access Data Projects) are basically on their way out. Support for them appeared to dwindle in Access versions 2007 and 2010 and, if I err not, Access 2013 does not support them at all. I wouldn't really recommend using an ADP and I believe that's the position of most MS Access developers at this point.

Comment: HK1 is right that ADP is not supported in Access 2013. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954(office.15).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj618413(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: In fact the ADP issue is much attached to the fact that oleDB and end of life support for oleDB in SQL server been announced. In fact even using SQL Azure, you really don't have support for oleDB and they recommend Open Database connectivity. So not only are ADP's in regards to Access on the way out, but more important is oleDB is on its way out and thus the recommend approach of using the Open Database connection standard remains the best choice when connecting to SQL server with Access.